# How to extract exact coding from APK?

Tags: android, apk

I got the java source code from Apk, but this is not the exact original java code from application . when i compare the both(Original and extracted)codes there are so many different.ex(some function does't appear in the extracted code)

Can we get java code same as original(executable) ?

It is possible or not?.

Comment: `It is possible or not?.` **NO**.

Comment: disable all compiler optimizations when building.

Answer (score 7):

> Can we get java code same as original(executable) ?

No.